npm validator returns false in mongoose validation but still submits query
I am practicing mongoose validation. I am trying to get the name field in my mongoose schema to validate for alphabet and space but no numbers. While using the npm validator, the validator.isAlpha function () is returning false but mongoose still creates the document in my database. I am not sure exactly what is happening because I thought that is the validation fails then the document should not be created. any ideas or suggestions?
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a name'],
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: [40, 'A tour name must have less or equal than 40 characters'],
      minlength: [10, 'A tour name must have more or equal then 10 characters'],
      // validate: [validator.isAlpha, ' Tour name must only contain characters']
      validate: {
        validator: function (val) {

          console.log(val);
          console.log(validator.isAlpha(this.name, 'en-US', { ignore: ' ' }));


          validator.isAlpha(this.name, 'en-US', { ignore: ' ' });

        },
        message: 'At tour must only contain letters'
      }
    }
  }

console.log(val) prints the string (i.e. "john doe 35") and console.log(validator ...) prints false.

You did not return the validated result in validator function.
See custom-validators
return validator.isAlpha(this.name, 'en-US', { ignore: ' ' });

Thanks so much. It makes so much sense, can't believe I didn't catch that.
